# TextField() - filter backspace key away with event listener

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

How to prevent a specific key such as backspace key functioning from TextField editable field, preventDefault does not seem to work:

```
public function handleEvents(evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
 if (evt.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP) {
 if (evt.keyCode==8){
   evt.preventDefault () ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend listening for the KEY_DOWN event if anything, but likely that won't work either. IIRC these type of events are a bit special and you can't really stop them. 
What I suspect you need to do is to store a copy of the text and whenever you detect a change you don't like just set it back to your stored version.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is set focus to another temporary (and off-stage) text field and in my keydown handler return focus to the my text field for the keys I want to get through. Setting focus just for keys you want to filter out also works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding evt.stopImmediatePropagation()

Comment: Did you add both prevent defaul and stop propagation? Also try adding the event handler on stage

Comment: not working:  TextField() gets the event 1st, but I also added same listener to stage, there was no difference with both preventDefault and stopImmediate..